# How to set search input focused when user typed something using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard-events

I created an application to list all products, and user can search for products using different ways, one of them is scanning barcode, usually, user should focus on the search input and scan the barcode, this is working fine.

But when the input (search input) is not focused, I want to make it default so that when user typed something, or scanned barcode, this input get focused before keydown or keypress.

Is that possible? for example if we can get an event before (keydown) or (keypress) then we can focus on the input so easy.

(Same idea if user pasted a text from clip board using control+v the the default search input focused and pasted to it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an event before keydown, you can just use keydown:

```
$(document).bind('keydown',function(e){
    $('input').focus();
});
```

See this [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/nec1r18e/)

Comment: wow! how I missed this? what about pasting? and the dose the barcode scanner trigger keydown?

Comment: Pasting also works (as you can try out with the jsfiddle). Wouldn't know about the barcode scanner as I don't have the code for that.

Comment: oh yess, keydown can detect control key and the input get focused, then when pressing v the input will pasted on the input... nice

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible if you add an event listener to the window object.

Example:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  
  jQuery(window).keydown(function(ev) {
    
    if (ev.target.tagName === 'INPUT' || ev.target.tagName === 'TEXTAREA')
      return;
    
    jQuery('#mydefaulttextbox').focus()
      
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
This is my default input:
<input id="mydefaulttextbox" type="text" />

<p>
This is another input:
<input type="text" />
</p>
```

The keydown binding is used because the character are only impressed when the keyup or keypress event is received.

Answer (score 0):

You also don't need jQuery for this.

```
<input type='text' id='bar_code_input' name='bar_code_input' />
<script type='text/javascript'>
 document.addEventListener('keypress', function(){
    var bc_input = document.getElementById('bar_code_input');
    bc_input.focus();
 });
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5d51z8rr/

Comment: This is correct but it loses first character for sure and test it also.

Comment: I used keypress as an example, you can use whatever event you'd like.  I'd also suggest capturing the event itself as it may be useful for what you're doing.

Comment: For sure @Laurens there are a ton of edge cases, this doesn't factor in mobile either.